# SQL request with list is not iterated in python

Tags: python, sql, list, for-in-loop

i have a **list** that a created after executing the sql request:

```
for w in ws.iter_rows (min_row = 1, min_col = 1, max_col = 1):
               
 for cell in w:
      termowner = cell.value
      zinput.append(str(termowner))
```

The list consists of values that i need to use in next sql query, but some reason the query is not iterate, so i get sql query result consists of a single value:

```
for j in range(len(zinput)):
 print(j,zinput[j])
 print(counter)

 cursor.execute ("select phone_number from clients where clients_id = ?",zinput[j])
```

Pls, does anyone know how to solve the problem.

The whole code:

```
zinput=[]
```

for w in ws.iter_rows (min_row = 1, min_col = 1, max_col = 1):

```
 for cell in w:
      termowner = cell.value
      zinput.append(str(termowner))
```

print(zinput)
counter = 0

for j in range(len(zinput)):
print(j,zinput[j])
print(counter)

```
 cursor.execute ("select phone_number from clients where clients_id = ?",zinput[j])
        
 results = cursor.fetchall()
 counter +=1
 print(results)
 print('iter',counter, 'done')
```

Comment: Why do you iterate lists with index?  `for client_id in zinput:` should be easier to do. did you `print(zinput)` after you filled it? What does it contain?

Comment: use 4 spaces as indentation ... not 1 or 2 - then you see directly if your "cursor.execute(.-..)" is INISDE your loop or OUTSIDE